# Episode 309: Who saved Usopp on the bridge at Enies Lobby?

Tags: one-piece

Does somebody know what happened on the bridge at Enies Lobby after Usopps speech to Luffy (This isn't hell!), when the three Marines attacked him and he didn't manage to hit them? 
Suddenly he got rescued, but who did that? I guess it was Dragon but is there any proof?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the manga Usopp was saved by Zoro, but in the anime it seems **Usopp was saved by a stray [Rankyaku](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Rokushiki/Rankyaku) Gaichou shot from [Lucci](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Rob_Lucci)**. He got extremely lucky that it hit the three of them.

Below are screenshots from chapter 309. At 15:43 Lucci releases the shot. At 15:46, Luffy dodges the shot and it goes upwards. At 15:56 it hits the Marines next to Usopp.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]